# Merge multiple Access database into one big database

Tags: database, ms-access, merge, database-performance

I have multiple ~50MB Access 2000-2003 databases (MDB files) that only contain tables with data. The *data-databases* are located on a server in my enterprise that can take ~1-2 second to respond (and about 10 seconds to actually open the 50 MDB file manually while browsing in the file explorer). I have other databases that only contain forms. Most of those *forms-database* (still MDB files) are actually copied from the server to the client (after some testing, the execution looks smoother) before execution with a batch file. Most of those *forms-databases* use table-links to fetch the data from the *data-databases*.

Now, my question is: is there any advantage/disadvantage to merge all *data-databases* from my ~50MB databases to make one big database (let's say 500MB)? Will it be slower? It would actually help to clean up my code if I wouln't have to connect to all those different databases and I don't think 500MB is a lot, but I don't pretend to be really used to Access by any mean and that's why I'm asking. If Access needs to read the whole MDB file to get the data from a specific table, then it would be slower. It wouldn't be really that surprising from Microsoft, but I've been pleased so far with MS Access database performances.

There will never be more than ~50 people connected to the database at the same time (most likely, this number won't in fact be more than 10, but I prefer being a little bit conservative here just to be sure).

Comment: If what you have is working nicely I wouldn't change too much in the way of structure.

Comment: Well, I'm always looking to improve performances. Just having to connect to one bigger database could actually be faster than connecting to multiple smaller databases, hence my interrogation.

Comment: 500 Mb is a lot for Access IMO.  You can run up to 2 gigs in the later versions of Access but I wouldn't advise it in a shared datafile situation.

Comment: Thank you for your input. One of the 50MB database only has one table with all the content of our LDAP directory (~about 35k rows). For me it's nothing, I'm used to work with MySQL on PHP environment (phpMyAdmin). Seems like it's already a lot for Access. But as I said, I've been pleased so far with performances: seeking through the 35k rows is really quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db engine does not read the entire MDB file to get information from a specific table.  It must read information from the system tables (hidden tables whose names start with MSys) to determine where the data you need is stored.  Furthermore, if you're using a query to retrieve information from the table, and the db engine can use an index to determine which rows satisfy the query's `WHERE` clause, it may read only those rows from the table.

However, you have issues with your network's performance.  When those lead to dropped connections, you risk corrupting the MDB.  That is why Access is not well suited for use in wide area networks or with wireless connections.  And even on a wired LAN, you can suffer such problems when the network is flaky.

So while reducing the amount of data you pull across the network is a good thing, it is not the best remedy for Access on a flaky network.  Instead you should migrate the data to a client-server db so it can be kept safe in spite of dropped connections.

Comment: As I said below, migration to a client-server db is not an option actually (but might be in the future). As for dropped connection, the databases are backed up at least once a day and data aren't that critical. But you still answer my main question by saying Access doesn't go through the whole file. It means that seeking through the same table from a 50MB database and a 2GB database would take the same time, right? Noy too much disadvantages then, if we don't take data corruption (whole db corrupted) into account.

Comment: @dnLL And all of your users concurrently working on the same db

Comment: @dnLL Not the same time exactly, but perhaps not enough of a time difference to be concerned about.  Reading meta information from large system tables can take longer than from small system tables.

Comment: @HansUp And for data corruption, suppose you have 2 different users running a local MDB file that contains the forms and the linked tables from the MDB on the server. Even if the same recordset is open for edition on both computers, I never got any error. If for some reason the network fails, the connection is usually still closed and the data not updated if the *rs.Update* hasn't been done. How could the data really get corrupted?

Comment: OK, I see you want to challenge the corruption issue.  I can't supply low level details about how that happens.  And I've almost never personally encountered such problems in a production application because I followed the advice of experienced Access developers, including MVPs, about best practices to avoid corruption.  Afraid I can't offer anything more.

Comment: And is there any specific place to find those MVPs and/or best practices? I just need to know more on Access. It will help to convince the IT department of my enterprise that a real server-db is needed. But in the meantime, I have to work with the tools I have, and this tool is Access 2007 (with the old MDB format however) :p

Comment: I don't know of any one place which consolidates all best practice information.  For MS Access on a WAN, see what Albert Kallal has to say: http://www.kallal.ca/Wan/Wans.html

Comment: @HansUp interesting read even if this is from 2003 (with some updates at the end). However, I never encountered any of my MDB file being corrupted, and I've seen a lot of disconnects or computers hanging up for no reason with the database opened and it has never been an issue yet. Is it because Access 2007 uses a different way to handle the data? I must say that I don't understand the logic behind removing the data from the file when loading it to RAM. I can have 2 distinct computers loading the same recordset at the same time and it has never been a problem neither (for read-only).

Answer (score 1):

You are walking on thin ice here.
Access will handle your scenario, but is not really meant to allow so many concurrent connections.
Merging everything in a big database (500mb) is not a wise move.
Have you tried to open it from a network location?

As far as I can suggest, I will use a backend SqlServer Express to merge all the tables in a single real client-server database.
The changes required by client mdb front-end should not be very pervasive.

Comment: In theory, the maximum number of concurrent users is 255, 50 should not be a problem *on a well-written database*. The maximum size for an MS 2010 database is 2gb, so 500mb is hardly a large database. The only important point, which is relevant for **any** system is that it should be well-designed. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx

Comment: By "so many", you're talking about 50? I really think this is a really small number, for me "so many" means like >1k. I guess Access has its limits then. As for SqlServer, it isn't really an option. I do not have administrator rights on either the network or the computer company. I can create or edit MDB files but I can't install anything. I'm just trying to do my best to help my peers being more efficient at their work with those small databases.

Comment: Thanks Remou for your input. But the fact that the server is located onto a distant server that pings >1s and that the tables are linked don't have any impact versus the database size? When I'm linking the same table from a 500MB database and from a 50MB database, it takes the same time because Access doesn't care about the other tables? Or it reads the whole database even if it doesn't need to? That's more what my question is about. I could do some testing but I'm lazy and I honestly prefer to look for someone more used to Access like you to see what you have to say about it.